# Как упростить схему деплоя?

Tags: git, развертывание

Первый раз работаю в небольшой команде на внутрикорпоративном проекте. Изучить гит более-менее осилил. Теперь мучаюсь с деплоем. Суть такова:

Используем стандартную схему веток (master, develop, topic). Программируем и верстаем у себя на локалке. Есть боевой сервер. Он же и git-сервер. Он же и тестовый сервер :) Сервер содержит 2 веб-приложения. Первое мы пуллим из master-ветки — релиз готов, второе — из develop — тестируем, прежде чем мастер пулить.

Так вот, чтобы банально выложить малюсенькое изменение feature ветки в продакшн (или хотя бы в тест) мне приходится превозмогать рутину:

1. Переключиться с feature на develop, обновить ветку.
2. Смержить feature, запушить develop
3. Переключиться на master, обновить её
4. Смержить develop, запушить master
5. Подключиться к боевому серверу сделать пулл на develop-приложении
6. Подключиться к боевому серверу сделать пулл на master-приложении
7. ???
8. "А тут ещё букву поправьте, пожалуйста"
9. goto 1

Это можно ли как-то всё упросить? Я уверен, что-то делаю неправильно.

Comment: Скажите, а при деплое приложения ещё какие-то действия производятся? Права файлам выставить, логи почистить, вебсервер ребутнуть?

Comment: @NickVolynkin 1) А как сделать лучше, подскажете? Проект внутрикорпоративный, и этот сервер стоит буквально в соседнем кабинете и пользуются им от силы человек 500-1000 (не в день, а вообще). 2) Нет. Некоторые сервисные вещи делаем по крону, а не при деплое. Так же у нас стоит gulp и заливаем уже минимизированные файлы, например.

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что на сервере просто есть две разных папки с git-репозиториями и из этих папок раздаются соответственно тестовая и боевая версия сайта?

Comment: Про Gulp – вы исходные или минимизированные файлы в git складываете? Или то и другое? У разработчика или на сервере выполняется минимизация?

Comment: Есть общий bare-гит репозиторий куда мы пушим и пуллим. А так вы правы. Боевой и тест просто 2 локальные папки настроенные на пулл с этого git-репозитория.

Comment: Уточню вопрос: из bare-репозитория в конкретные папки как попадают файлы? Делаете `git --work-tree=/path/to/test checkout .`?

Comment: подключаюсь по ssh
cd папка проекта
git pull origin master
происходит fast-forward и всё. Так как вы говорите не пробовал если честно.

Comment: Gulp собирает воединно и минимизирует в PHPStorm'e по кнопке Ctrl+S. Да пушим уже .min файлы (ну и обычные тоже). Криво?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50361/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-groza).

Comment: В принципе не проблема разделить test production и git сервера на отдельные машины. Суть моих мучений не изменится.

Comment: jenkins, ansible. devops во все поля

Comment: @rjhdby вроде хватает gitlab-ci )

Comment: Как успехи ваши с этой задачей?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пункты 1-2 - это очень упрощенный (где убрано к примеру тестирование) процесс, который делает каждый разработчик. Это его обычный цикл.

Пункт 3-4 - это релиз. Он не должен делать обычным разработчиком. Он делается релиз-менеджером (или ответственным человеком, назначенным на этом). Он не делается на каждый чих, а по процессу - раз в две недели или [два раза в день](https://habrahabr.ru/company/badoo/blog/317700/).

Пункты 5-8 делаются нажатием одной (максимум двух кнопок) или запуском одного скрипта. Он запускается на специальном билд сервере ([для маленькой такой компании](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74sUFG_Lp8I) это может быть одна машина и для сборки, и для тестов и для репозитория). Сам скрипт сборки обычно делает следующее

- git clone / git archive
- прогон скрипта, который фиксит конфиги, шаблоны (вы же не хотите показывать всем программистам пароли к базе на проде?)
- запуск скрипта, который процессит css, минимизирует js и тому подобное.
- прогон юнит тестов (они здесь, так как после минимизации могут быть проблемы:) )
- архивирование и занесение архива в надежное место
- подключаемся к прод серверу(серверам) и заливаем туда архив.
- архив распаковывается на сервере в отдельную папку, правится конфиг nginx/apache или симлинка и сервер рестартует. (можно конечно остановить сервер, перетереть файлы и запустить сервер, но если что то пошло не так...).
- на проде проганяются минимальные тесты (к примеру, что главная страница возвращает 200 код, а не 500).
- и в git добавляется тег с ссылкой на релиз.

Этот скрипт пишеться один раз и потом подганяется по мере надобности.

также этот скрипт следует дополнить, что бы он мог работать и с develop веткой.

Теперь упрощаем жизнь. В хуки на гит сервере добавляем этот скрпит, что бы при пуше в девелом/мастер автоматом запускалось и, как результат, деплоилось на тестовый сервер/прод. Мердж в мастер обычным программистам запрещается.

Теперь все выглядит так. Разработчик взял фичу, сделал под нее ветку, сделал. После мержда в девелом (или через мердж реквест) его код автоматом выливается на тестовое окружение. Если вдруг так случилось, что он все сломал - он должен фиксить.

Если так не подходит, можно скрипт запускать на CI - один с самых популярных - jenkins. В результате деплой - это просто нажать одну кнопку.

**Q/A**

- а почему не пулить прямо на боевом сервере? Если кто то уведет сервер, у него будет доступ к полной истории разработки. Это нужно?
- у меня никто не уведет историю гита, поэтому я буду пулить. [уже было](https://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/)
- зачем сколько сложностей с скриптом? А представьте, что багу нашли среди ночи и нужно срочно фиксить. Наличие такого скрипта сильно упрощает жизнь.
- а можно без тестов? можно. Но лучше сделать какие-то минимальные.

Comment: "Пункт 3-4 - это релиз." — к сожалению, в реальности так не получается. Трогать мастер раз в 1-2 дня. Поставили задачу уровня поменяй логотип в шапке на новогодний — и чтоб к обеду было.

Comment: Спасибо. А так всё круто. Буду смотреть на Jenkins. Всегда хотел изучить.

Comment: На самом деле никто не мешает делать релиз постоянно. Но новогодняя шапка делается через hotfix c конфигом, которым можно отключить. В следующий раз нужно будет только конфиг поправить.

Comment: то есть, я правильно понимаю, что чтобы изменить одну строчку в коде на продакшене мне скрипт будет архивировать ВЕСЬ проект и переносить его удаляя старый, прогонять тесты, чистить временные файлы и т. п., когда как при помощи пула я обновлю только изменённые файлы за 5 сек? Или как-то можно упростить?

Comment: да, Вы правильно понимаете. Но не до конца. Хорошо, если у Вас всего один сервер и два скрипта. Тогда можете больше ничего не делать. А если ферма на 300 машин? А если так случилось, что хостер решил "прилечь". А что, если хочется релиз перед выкаткой протестить? Иногда, даже исправление одной строки может приводить к таким сложным и трудновылавливаемым багам...

**удаляя старый,** как раз нет. Не нужно удалять. Мало чего, вдруг нужно будет сделать откат.

Comment: Если делать методом пула (откинем безопасность), то можно сначала спулить на тестовый сервер, потом уже на боевой — как и делали.

Comment: Для 300 машин-то понятно все по другому надо, как вы говорите. Но я в вопросе уточнил что это внутрикорпоративный проект, где вход по пропускам и доступа к сайту извне нету и за доступ (физический) к серверу отвечает специальная служба. Мне кажется, для разных случаев будут разные способы деплоя. Понятно, что на публичном хостинге гит юзать ну никак нельзя. Я не собираюсь с вами спорить, вы лучше меня разбираетесь. Просто хочу сам понять.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что Вы решили спросить, как это сделать "правильно" и "хорошо", но при этом Вы совершенно не хотите делать так, потому что считаете, что Ваш способ в Вашем случае самый лучший. Я не вижу смысла переубеждать и что то доказывать. Делайте так, как Вам удобно. Возможно, у Вас будет специальный человек, который будет приходить с листиком бумаги и фиксить код прямо на живим сервере (при этом не забыв расписаться в журнале и приклеить туда этот самый листик с инструкциями):)

Comment: Дело в том, что вы не объяснили, почему это "правильно" и "хорошо" для моей ситуации (в чем и была суть поста), написав кейсы которые у меня в компании никогда не случатся: у меня нет фермы 300 компьютеров; историю гита будьте, уверены, не украдут; про тест я уже сказал. Разве в деплойменте может быть только одно истинно-общее золотое решение?

Comment: В оригинальном вопросе не было всех этих "уточнений" о том, что это внутренний сайт, полурежимное предприятие.
Почему мой способ лучше? все очень просто - он убирает рутину (где можно сделать ошибки), и он прикрывает спину. А это самое главное.

Comment: Ваш способ отличный и общепринятый, согласен. Именно поэтому я и галку поставил. Единственное что меня смущает — это то, что внесение мелких правок в течение дня создадут куда большую рутину и простой проекта из-за копирования кучи файлов.

Comment: Если Вы сделаете все до конца (то есть, используя хуки и тому подобное), то просто сделав мердж в мастер, все остальное закрутиться автоматом и в 99% случаев отработаем магически и быстро. И Вам при этом все равно, будет делать это 2 секунды или 10 - вручную Вы это точно сделаете медленее. Но если страшно боитесь лишнего копирования - rsync Ваш друг.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо. Будем пробовать!

Answer (score 3):

Давайте для начала разделим сущности. В процессе задействованы:

- Боевой сервер.
- Тестовый сервер.
- Сервер git
- Некоторый "агент деплоя". Сейчас вы развёртываете (деплоите) руками, хорошо бы делегировать эту задачу серверу непрерывной интеграции (continuous integration server, CI server). В простейшей версии это реализуется хуками на сервере git.
- Исходный код приложения
- Дистрибутив приложения — в вашем случае это минимизированные с помощью Gulp файлы.

В данный момент задачи всех серверов выполняет один, а дистрибутив хранится вместе с кодом. Давайте тем не менее рассматривать их как отдельные и стремиться к низкой связности между ними (как в ООП между классами). Это даст нашей системе гибкость и гораздо большую масштабируемость. В частности, не будем полагаться на то, что что-то лежит рядом на одном диске или доступно по локальной сети.

Что нужно сделать:

1. Отделить дистрибутив от кода. При коммите запускаем gulp, получаем минимизированные файлы, (опционально) пакуем их в архив, перемещаем на сервер и там разворачиваем. Минимизированный код хранить не нужно, т.к. мы всегда можем его получить из исходного.
2. Реализовать *в коде* сценариий развёртывания. Хотя бы предусмотреть место для действий, производимых на сервере: заполнение конфигов, перезагрузка сервисов и т.п. Как говорилось выше, это делается через git-hook и/или сервер CI.
3. Автоматизировать реакцию на изменения в репозитории: при пуше в определённые ветки должно происходит развёртывание в определённом окружении. Поскольку сценарий развёртывания у нас теперь в коде, мы можем его.

И в организации работы:

1. Пересмотреть порядок релизов. Сейчас вы как будто бы релизите каждую опечатку и релизить может каждый. Стоит так же подумать о защите ветки master (в том числе от своих неосторожных действий).

---

## Работающий пример

Предлагаю проводить эксперимент на примере GitLab.com (т.е. будем использовать облачный сервис). Выбор субъективный, вот аргументы за:

1. Есть возможность создавать бесплатные приватные репозитории. (Т.е. ваш коммерческий код в относительной безопасности.)
2. В комплекте есть GitLab CI, тесно интегрированный с репозиторием.
3. Доступны (в том числе для приватных репозиториев) бесплатные раннеры — условно, виртуальные машины, на которых мы будем выполнять наши задачи.

Аргумент против: если проект будет расти, когда-нибудь бесплатной лицензии не будет хватать для всех задач.

> [Рабочий пример с конвейерами и логами выложен на GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com/nick.volynkin/gulp-demo/pipelines).

Основной файл, описывающий выполняемый сценарий, лежит в корневой папке проекта и называется `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
image: alpine

stages:
  - gulp
  - test
  - package
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

gulp:
  stage: gulp
  image: node:latest
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script: node_modules/.bin/gulp compress
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist
    expire_in: 10 minutes

test:
  stage: test
  script: ls dist
  script: echo 'run tests here'

package:
  stage: package
  script: tar -czvf packaged.tar.gz dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - packaged.tar.gz

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script: echo 'deploy on master'
  only:
    - master

deploy_test:
  stage: deploy
  script: echo 'deploy on develop'
  only:
    - develop
```

Зависимости мы вынесем в [конфиг для npm — package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json). В файле `gulpfile.js` описана задача `compress`, обеспечивающая минимизацию.

Скриншот окна конвейеров CI:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат работы: архив `packaged.tar.gz`, в нём `dists/hello.js`, в нём

```
!function(t,e,i){t.title="New title"}(window,document);
```

Comment: Все верно. Ок. Я согласен. Нужно разделять мух от котлет. Нужно делать минификацию при деплое выгружать только мин файлы - это и будет дистрибутив в некотором роде. Но тем не менее сам процесс деплоя вызывает боль. Какой несложный CI можете посоветовать?

Comment: И плохо ли пуллить изменения на боевой из гита?

Comment: @GroZa вот этот советую. https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/. Сейчас напишу про него пример.

Comment: @GroZa если не трудно, добавьте в вопрос команды, с которыми вы gulp используете. А то я конкретно с ним не работал.